Generating Bloch State from Kohn Sham States in Quantum Espresso
As I understand it:

Quantum Espresso performs an SCF calculation to find Kohn-Sham orbitals. These KS orbitals are stored in the wfc files.
These are then used in an NSCF calculation to find Bloch states: $\psi(\textbf{r}) = e^{i \textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r}} u(\textbf{r})$

For purely academic purposes I wanted to pick up these Bloch states and see (for instance) that they indeed obey translation symmetry. Yet I am not sure if QE actually saves Bloch states in a file.
I presumed that when one is making subsequent calculations, Bloch states would be the principal ingredient (not the KS orbitals). Hence for instance the linear response function $\epsilon$ in Yambo uses Bloch states:
$$
\epsilon_{\alpha, \alpha}(\omega) = 1 + \frac{16\pi}{\Omega}\sum_{c, v}\sum_{\textbf{k}} \frac{1}{E_{c\textbf{k}} - E_{v\textbf{k}}} \frac{|<v\textbf{k}|\textbf{p}_\alpha + i[V^{NL}, \textbf{r}_\alpha]|c\textbf{k}>|}{({E_{c\textbf{k}} - E_{v\textbf{k}}})^2 - (\omega+i \gamma)^2)}
$$
So how does one proceed to generate a Bloch state from the wfc files?

What you are looking for is just the wavefunctions. You should just look up the documentation for how QE stores the wavefunctions. Those KS wavefunctions are already in Bloch states form; QE never stores anything else than Bloch states. I am, however, not sure if QE stores it in position basis or momentum basis.

To read the wavefunctions generated by QE, see this. QE seems to store them in a momentum basis.

Also check if QE stores the Block function $\psi$ or just the unit-cell periodic part $u$. Both are perfectly good choices.
